Asking a series of questions
I have written two question series on cogsci, on morality and on jealousy.
I did this, as when I started writing a question, I realised I had many questions within the question, so structured it into a series.
Is this an acceptable practice for our site?  (I do not want to make a practice of something that we do not want here.)
If so, should the questions be linked within each question as a series, and if so, how?

Great question, will be worthwhile to discuss!

I think you did it right, one question per, well, question. But I will post a full answer so others can downvote me if they disagree.

I think it's perfectly fine to ask a serious of questions about some topic. I personally do not think, though, that this means those questions should have a line like "This is the i-th question of a serious of questions about x" in them. (This is what @WhyDoYouThinkThatIsTrue has done and I am assuming that the question is about this point.) I have three arguments for my point of view: 

Questions should be understandable by themselves. If there is not
enough information provided in the question to understand or answer
it, the question should be edited. Having that said, there is of
course nothing wrong with providing links to other questions that
are related.
Questions that refer to the same topic will have at least one common
tag and thus will show up as related questions anyway.
It is a goal of the site to become an important source for questions
on cognitive science. Not only for those that are already members,
but also for those who do, say, a google search on some topic. For
someone who is interested in one thing and finds the answer on the
site, other questions might or might not be of interested to him,
even if they are related. Having a line like "This is..." in the
answer might imply that the other questions in the series are
"required" to read, which should not be the case in my opinion.

I want to make it clear that I am not suggesting that @WhyDoYouThinkThatIsTrue has to edit his questions. But if we are to think about guidelines, then this would be my proposal.

@WhyDoYouThinkThatIsTrue I didn't mean to say that your questions were not understandable by themselves. They are. That was a general thing. Maybe my second point is the most important one in my line of reasoning. But that's just my take. As to your 2nd comment: there is nothing wrong with asking a question and then posting an answer yourself. This is somewhere in the Help-pages.
